# Js | Как преобразовать полученный элемент из HTMLCollection в строку/list

Tags: javascript

Если у элемента есть id мы можем использовать его как будто переменную в js.

А если нужно обратиться к классу то можно использовать getElementsByClassName.

Но это будут разные вещи. Это наглядно видно если вывести в консоль, тот что мы получили по классу будет HTMLCollection а просто по id будет... строкой?

Необходимо что-бы. Тот к которому мы обращаемся по классу выглядил так же как будто мы к нему по id обращаемся.

```js
    <p id="someid" class="someclass">Text</p>
    <script>
    console.log(someid);
    console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('someclass'));
    </script>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем вам это?))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Так еще можно...

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('.someclass'));
```

```html
<p id="someid" class="someclass">Text</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log(someid);
console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('someclass')[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<p id="someid" class="someclass">Text</p>
```

Соответственно если много элементов, то надо будет не `[0]`  а проходить в цикле